# To write an xml string to azure data lake storage

Tags: python, xml, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake, xmlwriter

When I try to write an xml string to azure datalake storage I am getting error as file not found. I am using synapse notebook with python to write the file. Synapse notebook and the datalake storage are in the same resource group

I tried with to_xml({file_path/output.xml}).
But this does not work with xml strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use pandas, what I assume you use it:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
xml = '''<data><row><tex>text example</tex></row></data>'''

df = pd.read_xml(io.StringIO(xml))
print(df)

# Output in file
out ='StringXML.xml'
df.to_xml(f'{out}', index=False)
```

This will write into file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<data>
  <row>
    <tex>text example</tex>
  </row>
</data>
```

Comment: Belongs to your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77263707/12621346)

Comment: I want to write an xml string into adls storage and for this to_xml() does not work

Comment: The edited script works for simple xml file. In my case, it is a complicated xml file. So this removes most of the tags while copying to the adls with to_xml()

Answer (score 0):

`spark.sparkContext.parallelize([xml_string], 1)` converts the **xml_string** into a distributed collection (**RDD**) and specifies that it should be stored as one partition.

`.saveAsTextFile(adls_path)` saves the content of the RDD to the specified **ADLS Gen2** path as a text file.

I have tried the below approach in Pyspark:

```
xml_string = """
<root>
  <person>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <age>30</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Jane Smith</name>
    <age>28</age>
  </person>
</root>
"""
adls_path = "abfss://folder002@dileepstoragegen2.dfs.core.windows.net/output.xml"
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("WriteXMLToADLS").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([xml_string], 1).saveAsTextFile(adls_path)
print("XML data has been written to ADLS Gen2.")
```

[image]

[image]

- The above Code converts the XML string into an RDD, and then saves it to your specified ADLS Gen2 path as a text file.
- This is a way to write data to ADLS Gen2 using distributed data processing capabilities provided by PySpark in Azure Synapse.

Comment: This does work and save the file as text file. But I want to save as an .xml file. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rootTag", "root").option("rowTag", "person").save(adls_path)
@Sam please try the above code and see if you to ADLS as an XML file using the spark-xml package